# TileOverlay: bounding map rectangle

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to convert a number of a tile (`x`,`y` and `zoom`) that I get in method `getTile(int x, int y, int zoom)` to latitude and longitude coordinates of this tile?
It would be best if you could name a method that will return `LatLngBounds` object ;-)

Is there anything like that in map api v2?

Comment: I have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883997/tileprovider-method-gettile-need-to-translate-x-and-y-to-lat-long

Comment: Marcin, I have put an answer to original question.