# android maps v2 api display metro lines overlay

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I would like to display metro lines in an Android application. In fact I need to place markers on several stations, and others on coordinates (LatLng). So, I would like to have google maps of Paris (Paris only for now), and stations over it.

I've already tried GroundOverlay, but it works with small images only I think, I get a NullPointerException when using full size map. (1000 x 1000 px). The image I use is this one http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Paris_Metro_map_complete.svg converted in .bmp.

Maybe another way could be to draw with lines & circle each stations, but it's a lot of work !

So my questions are :

1) I  there a way to display metro & tram on android maps v2 api, just like the old maps.google.com (website, not the android maps v1 api)?

2) Is there a way to use an image like that as an overlay for maps ?

3) If not, have you another idea ? Add circles & lines is a good idea you think ?

Hope I'm clear...
Thanks a lot !
Audric

Comment: a transparent overlay is ok, but my experience is, that it takes alot of work to get it done. also i had trouble getting the overlay exactly on right spot. last but not least, using big overlays can be very bad for the performance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [`TileOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay).

You may use SVG file directly with [svg-android library](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/), drawing parts of it into `Bitmap` and then convert into `byte[]` of PNG file for use in `TileProvider`.

I also don't see why would you get `NullPointerException` on a 1000x1000 px image. That is only 4MB in memory. Try converting it into PNG instead of BMP.

Comment: Ok, I 'm going to try with this.
I've found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883997/tileprovider-method-gettile-need-to-translate-x-and-y-to-lat-long to transform x,y, and zoom of getTile (from TileProvider) to latitude and longitude, but I don't find a way to extract a region in the SVG file. How can I do that ? It's what you say with 'drawing parts of it into Bitmap'